# А как решаются вопросы с минусами из-за мести

Tags: обсуждение

Вот буквально 20 минут назад какой-то нехороший пользователь прошелся по списку вопросов (буквально за одну минуту), в которых я принимал участие, и понаставил в каждом из них по минусу. Я очень сомневаюсь в обоснованности данных оценок. Похоже, что человек действовал под воздействием каких-то эмоций. Бывало ли здесь такое раньше? И как решались подобные вопросы?

Comment: Да, бывало. Система через 24 часа откатит минуса автоматом. По теме: [раз](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2877/)

Comment: Не волнуйтесь, такое случается. Система откатит минусы и вернёт вам репутацию в течение суток.

Comment: @AK , Спасибо, понял.

Comment: @AK, ели вопросы были не его, а разных пользователей, то я не уверен, что откатит. Хотя это была бы какая-то странная месть...

Comment: @AK, Только если минусование было серийное. Но если имеет место целенаправленное минусование конкретным юзером конкретного юзера - то с ним будет проведена воспитательная беседа :-)

Comment: и [два](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4401/%D0%9B%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5-html-css-%D0%90%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2), почему-то удалённый топикстартером

Comment: @AK, потому что его закрыли как дубликат

Comment: @Grundy А как понять, куда он вёл?

Comment: @AK, набрать 10000 репутации :-)

Comment: @AK так не сложно догадаться почему удалён ;-)

Comment: @AK, он вел [туда же](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2540), куда направили и этот.